# which design pattern to use for easy addition of new algorithms?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to solve which design pattern I have to use for this problem:

I have classes Computer and Algorithm

1) There could be lot of instances of Computer

2) Every Computer can have exactly one instance of Algorithm

3) Algorithm is some kind of abstract, it should have one void "compute"

4) the concrete algorithm is in class ConcreteAlg1, ConcreteAlg2 etc. so there could be lot of different classes of concrete algorithm

My goal is to create an Computer instance where I create new ConcreteAlg235 instance without knowing that some class ConcreteAlg235 was added. So my goal is to easily create new algorithm classes and create its instances in instance of class Computer without editing code of class Computer.

Think about that like I want to do some proprietary software and give an opportunity to add new algorithms for users,and to have easy maintainability of source code for myself.

Thank you for any ideas

Comment: I wonder why this question was anonimously down-voted?

Comment: @aviad I would like to know reason too.

Comment: I'll vote you back up until the downvoter explains

Comment: I would like to do, but without knowing reasons for downwote it is not easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Comment: the name is more suitable but the idea in this particular case is pretty much the same...

Comment: No, you're looking for the command pattern....the swapping part (without recompiling, etc) is only easily possible depending on the technology you use.  The command pattern allows a series of classes to process an event and the series can be a mutable series.  With strategy, you have to swap out the implementation...I see you mean the same thing as I do really and there are different ways to do it but the correct pattern that fits is the command pattern.

Comment: @vinnybad Command pattern is more suitable to operations like *undo/redo* where you don't really know what to *undo* or *redo*, you just call the command. The way I see it, is,  you have a component and what to perform several different actions you have several `commands` to perform. In the other hand, you have one component that will follow some `strategy` or the other depending upon some conditions.

Comment: @OscarRyz The defining property of a strategy pattern is that the implementation can be selected at runtime...not whether or not something was added or removed.  In reality, it really depends on what implementation he chooses to use.  The implementation details will reveal which pattern has actually been chosen but in this case either can be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) for the Algorithm? This way you can be sure that when you instantiate the Computer you will expect an implementation of a Command interface with execute method (can be renamed to something more suitable)

Answer (score 0):

The strategy and command pattern are similar, yet different.  Strategy pattern allows you to swap implementations of a particular algorithm in and out.  What you're looking for here is the command pattern, which concrete classes implement a common interface.  You can add a public method to the Computer class and add onto an internally-held list of commands to process...however you decide to modify this list of algorithms per computer is up to you but this is one way to do it and is quite simple.